# Making my own 8x2 pin connector cable

Tags: connector, header

I am currently using two 8-wire ribbon cable to connect 2x8 pins on the Arduino to 2x8 pins on a board. This makes plugging/unplugging very tedious are the ends are not glued together like in a connector

[image]

**Question:** How can I create my own ribbon cables with connetors for 2x8 pins? After some researched I found IDC connectors somewhat suitable, but the connectors appear to have additional plastic like the clips which will obscure the 2 pins to each side of the 2x8 pins I'm plugging the cable into.

What other options do I have? I'm hoping for a 8x2 version of the following cable, what are such cables called?

[image]

Comment: How are your soldering skills? Would you want to solder your own cable or you are searching to buy a ready one?

Comment: @alexan_e I have basic soldering skills, able to solder components to pcb boards. I'm looking to both purchase and solder/crimp my own.

Comment: Can something like this be used? Or are these for inserting jumper cables and not for soldering wires into. http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PPTC082LFBN-RC/S7076-ND/810214

Comment: The double raw header you show can be either used on a PCB or with soldered wires. There is no limitation in the way it can be used.

Answer (score 3):

Pololu.com sells connectors like this, and they have precrimped wires as well.

[Wires](http://www.pololu.com/category/71/wires-with-pre-crimped-terminals).

2x8 [housing](http://www.pololu.com/product/1916).

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use the 0.1" (2.54mm) double row male headers on one side.

[image]

and a female 0.1" (2.54mm) double row header in the other side

[image]

Get some multicolor flat ribbon cable

[image]

and you can make your own cable at any length and pin count.

If you want you can reinforce the wire/plug connection using a hot glue gun, something that looks like

[image]

---

Another possible solution may be to use your current jumper wires, just use glue or hot glue to hold them together as one piece and should be fine.

Comment: Surely you're not suggesting they solder ribbon cable!

Comment: @JeannePindar Why not? What great universe power prevents anyone from doing so?

Comment: The laws of physics? Stripped and soldered ribbon cable inevitably breaks. It's bad enough for a one-time use, and this is on a connector.

Comment: @JeannePindar In that case embrace the impossible because I've been using them for years http://i.stack.imgur.com/AnQEM.jpg . I've got longer length versions too.

Answer (score 1):

The connectors in your last picture appear to me to be "AMPModu" connectors, made by AMP.  The housing are available in both single and double row.  The contacts are crimped on the wires, then inserted in the housing.

Answer (score 0):

**Make a PCB bridge**

Something like this:
[image]

Either use generic prototyping board or have a custom PCB made just for you. Then solder both male and female 8x2 header to it. Some manufacturers can also do flexible PCB boards. You can design the bridge using Eagle Cad and then you can shop for a manufacturer [here](http://pcbshopper.com/).

Comment: Can the flexible ones (Eg. Asus and MSI in the photo above) be bought off the shelf? Are the headers on both end of them standard parts that we can get off Digikey/Mouser?

Comment: Those are SLI bridges. I'm sure they can be bought somewhere, but they are not exactly what are you looking for.

Comment: I'm looking to connect two male 8x2 headers together, like 16 of the pins on the Arduino Mega, like shown in the main post.

Comment: but the arduino mega has female headers

Comment: Sorry meant female headers on the Arduino Mega